# Java check if Checkbox is checked

Tags: java, checkbox, awt

I use:

```
    CheckboxGroup cg = new CheckboxGroup();
    Checkbox c1 = new Checkbox("A", false, cg);
    Checkbox c2 = new Checkbox("B", false, cg);
    Checkbox c3 = new Checkbox("C", true, cg);
```

To create a group of three checkboxes. Now, I want to check which one of them is checked. I use:

```
if (c1.isSelected()) { }
```

but this gives `The method isSelected() is undefined for the type Checkbox`... Recommended solution is add cast to c1, I do so and it gives `Cannot cast from Checkbox to AbstractButton`... Again, how can I just check if a Checkbox if checked?

Comment: What's wrong with `CheckboxGroup#getSelectedCheckbox()`?

Comment: [Radio buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html) seems more appropriate than checkboxes if they are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use getState()

```
boolean checked = c1.getState();
if(c1.getState()) {
  //c1 is checked
} else if (c2.getState()) {
  //
}
```

**OR**

```
Checkbox cb = cg.getSelectedCheckbox();
if(null != cb) {
  //not checked
} else {
  System.out.println(cb.getLabel() + " is checked");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Checkbox::getState()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Checkbox.html#getState%28%29) or (as said in the comment) [`CheckboxGroup#getSelectedCheckbox()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CheckboxGroup.html#getSelectedCheckbox%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

1st of all java.awt.Checkbox doesn't have .isSelected() method in its super class, which is java.awt.Component.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Checkbox.html

please check the above link for Methods inherited from class java.awt.Component

2nd  .isSelected() method can be used if you use JCheckBox from javax.swing.JComponent;  but not CheckBox of AWT...

please go through below link..  and you can find .isSelected() which is inherited from  javax.swing.AbstractButton;

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBox.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the isChecked() method to be the winner.

```
 // Check to see if box is checked
 if (c1.isChecked()) {
      // Your code if the box is checked
 } else {
      // Your code if the box is not checked
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

judging by your use of `isSelected` i concluded you have 1 of 2 mistakes:

1. you want to use check box, if that is the case, then you should use `c1.getState()` and not `isSelected()`
2. you need `RadioBox` instead of `CheckBox` and then you can use the `isSelected()` method. 
   [check here about the two](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Answer (score -1):

you can try this code

```
// check is ckeck box id
if (check.isSelected()) {
           // your code for checked;
 } else {
           // our code for not checked;
 }
```