# Checkbox showing same results regardless of whether it is checked

Tags: java, checkbox

I have a problem using checkbox in Java. Regardless of whether the checkbox is checked, the result is always Yes. Can somebody help me check if there is any error with the code below please?

```
private String whippedCreamMethod(){
CheckBox checkBoxWhippedCream = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream_checkbox);
   if (checkBoxWhippedCream.isSelected()){
       whippedCream = "No";
   } else {
       whippedCream = "Yes";
   }
    return whippedCream;
```

}

Comment: Look at this post : [checkbox java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423485/java-check-if-checkbox-is-checked)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a method `isChecked()` rather than `isSelected()`;

```
final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
     if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
         checkBox.setChecked(false);
     }
```

from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html

Comment: Could you please mark it as the answer you were looking for?